# Select query with blank decimal column in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

In my VB.net project, i have used this (`select pid,pval,1 as amount,1 as calc from product`) example many times where i am using `integer` as a `blank column`. But tried a lot to use `decimal` as a blank column but couldn't find a way to do so.
How can i add a `blank decimal column` in my `select query`  
Please help me out.


NOTE: I am using MS Access 2007.

Comment: Im not sure I get what you want (Blank?) but `Select CDec(0.00)....`

Comment: Thanks @fred. That worked for me. Even i tried the same but used cdec(0) instead of cdec(0.00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select pid,pval, CDec(0.00) as amount, CDec(0.00) as calc from product`

Will do what you are after.